# Suppress "C source seen but `CC` undefined" in automake?

Tags: ocaml, autoconf, automake

I have a `Makefile.am` for compiling Ocaml source code with `ocamlbuild`. However, even
though I have

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign no-dependencies])
```

in my `configure.ac`, automake thinks that a C compiler must be present to install exectuables. That is, if I put in `Makefile.am` a target executable under `bin_PROGRAMS` that is to be built with ocamlbuild, autoreconf (version 1.11.3) tells me:

```
Makefile.am: C source seen but `CC' is undefined
Makefile.am:   The usual way to define `CC' is to add `AC_PROG_CC'
Makefile.am:   to `configure.ac' and run `autoconf' again.
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

I do *not* want to include `AC_PROG_CC` because my source code includes no C. It is pure Ocaml. What can I do? (I have the same problem with `libexec_PROGRAMS`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be unneeded, but will it hurt anything to simply add AC_PROG_CC to Makefile.am? Path of least resistance and all.

Working off this decade-old mailing list message:

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake/2003-01/msg00057.html

It sounds like you might need to define progname_SOURCES as empty. If I understand the post correctly, if you omit an explicit declaraction, progname_SOURCES will implicitly be defined as progname.c.

Comment: `AC_PROG_CC` will probably add unneeded tests, slowing down `configure`.

Comment: This one is how things should be done. Just set `progname_SOURCES` to the empty value. So I am declaring that this one is the "accepted answer".

Comment: I was struggling against a similar problem until I read this answer and realised that my "progname" contained invalid characters ('+'). Everything went fine after renaming my progname.

Answer (score 5):

If you add `AC_SUBST([CC])` to `configure.ac`, that will be enough to define the variable as far as Automake is concerned.